# can i insert multiple records once in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new in flutter and this is my first app ,i have this page which get Daylist() from another page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:jiyanUquraan/components/daylist.dart';
class Days extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DaysState createState() => _DaysState();
}
class _DaysState extends State<Days> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
        title: Text(
          'ژیان و قورئان',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"),
              fit: BoxFit.cover,
            ),
          ),
          child: DisplayList()),
    );
  }
}
```

The Daylist() is comes from this page :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:jiyanUquraan/classes/viewdigree.dart';
class DisplayList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DisplayListState createState() => _DisplayListState();
}
class _DisplayListState extends State<DisplayList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List digrees = [];
    double _value = 0;
    var widthView = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    Future<List> fetchDigrees() async {
      Map rdata = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
      var did = int.parse(rdata['d_id'].toString());
      print(did);
      var url =
          'http://10.0.2.2/jiyan/test/api/activities/activiy_list.php?d_id=$did';
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      for (var x in data) {
        Digree newdigree = Digree(x['index'], x['title_k'], x['title_a'],
            x['aya'], x['link'], x['activity_k'], x['activity_a']);
        digrees.add(newdigree);
      }
      print(digrees.length);
      print(data);
      return digrees;
    }
    return FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchDigrees(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          List digrees = snapshot.data;
          print(digrees);
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Center(
              child: Text("Loading"),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 20, 25, 20),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(snapshot.data[0].title_k,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.white)),
                  //for top margin
                  SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                  // dexription
                  Text(snapshot.data[0].aya,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26, color: Colors.yellow)),
                  // now populating your ListView for `Directionality`
                  Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      // Start activities
                      Column(
                          children: snapshot.data.map<Widget>((item) {
                        return Directionality(
                          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                          child: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
                                    border: Border.all(
                                        width: 2, color: Colors.white),
                                    color: Color.fromRGBO(230, 200, 200, 0.2)),
                                width: widthView,
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 25, 0, 25),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      item.activity_k,
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.justify,
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 28, color: Colors.white),
                                    ),
                                    SliderTheme(
                                      data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                                        activeTrackColor: Colors.red[700],
                                        inactiveTrackColor: Colors.red[100],
                                        trackShape:
                                            RectangularSliderTrackShape(),
                                        trackHeight: 4.0,
                                        thumbColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                        thumbShape: RoundSliderThumbShape(
                                            enabledThumbRadius: 12.0),
                                        overlayColor: Colors.red.withAlpha(32),
                                        overlayShape: RoundSliderOverlayShape(
                                            overlayRadius: 28.0),
                                      ),
                                      child: Slider(
                                        value: 0,
                                        min: 0,
                                        max: 100,
                                        divisions: 10,
                                        label: '$_value',
                                        onChanged: null,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        );
                      }).toList()),
                      // End activities
                      Text(snapshot.data[0].link,
                          textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26, color: Colors.yellow)),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

This page show data comes from server more than one row ,each row contain text with activity name and slider which will be the degree of that activity ,now I want to change the slider to determine the value as degree of that activity ,how can I insert all degrees together by clicking on buttun,

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. Check the guidelines for improvements: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i will try to clarify it

Comment: I made changes now

Answer (score 0):

You can use setter or getter functions inside your Degree class .when you do change slider you can set value in Degree class then get each list item value  on button click using any kind of loop on the degree list

if you want to set each list item degree with the change of one slider you can do this using loop and setter function  on your slider change